# Dirac delta doublet function in simple harmonic oscillation. Conditions imposed?

Tags: dirac-delta, greens-function, oscillatory-integral

I'm considering an at-rest simple harmonic oscillator (m,k) and want to model the force by a doublet (derivative of dirac delta) at t=0.
$$f = \delta'(t)$$
I've already considered the case for a dirac delta, and I'm supposing that a Green's function method will suffice. As normal,
$$G = \frac{1}{mw}\sin (w(t-t'))$$
For a dirac delta $f=\delta(t)$, the solution is clearly just $f=\frac{1}{mw}\sin(wt)$ by convolution. I believe this therefore imposes the condition that $\dot x(0^+) = 1/mw$, though I'm not entirely certain.

For doublet, applying integration by parts, I get that $f = \frac{1}{M}\cos(wt)$. However, this clearly cannot be true. In my mind, the idea of $\delta'(t)$ is a spike and a negative spike, meaning the behavior directly after must be $x=0$, since impulses cancel. However, this result clearly conflicts with that. I don't think I have the freedom to impose a coefficient of zero, so I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the notation, let's set $m=1$. Then, let me show that the solution to
$$
x''+w^2x=\delta'(t) \tag{1}
$$
such that $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$ is
$$
x(t)=\Theta(t)\cos(wt), \tag{2}
$$ where $\Theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside step function. Indeed, differentiating $x(t)$ twice we find
$$
x''(t)=\delta'(t)\cos(wt)-2w\delta(t)\sin(wt)-w^2\Theta(t)\cos(wt). \tag{3}
$$
It follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$
x''+w^2x=\delta'(t)\cos(wt)-2w\delta(t)\sin(wt). \tag{4}
$$
To show that the RHS of $(4)$ is equal to $\delta'(t)$, we notice that, for any [test function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) $f\in\cal{D}(\mathbb{R})$,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[\delta'(t)\cos(wt)-2w\delta(t)\sin(wt)]f(t)\,dt &=-(\cos(wt)f(t))'-2w\sin(wt)f(t)\big|_{t=0} \\
&=-f'(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(t)f(t)\,dt.\quad{\square} \tag{5}
\end{align}

---

To reconcile this result with your intuition, I suggest that you solve the ODE
$$
x''+w^2x=\frac{\delta(t+a)-\delta(t)}{a}
$$
and take the limit $a\to 0$ of the solution
$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{aw}[\Theta(t+a)\sin(w(t+a))-\Theta(t)\sin(wt)].
$$

Comment: I agree that the solution is $f=\cos(wt)$. I state as much in the q. I just don't see how this aligns with physical intuition. Using the limit definition doesn't clear much up either. Perhaps I would be better asking on a physics exchange.

Comment: You say you agree, but you also wrote in the question "this clearly cannot be true"...

Comment: I agree with the mathematical derivation. My question then was reconciling the physical and mathematical intuition. Whether my math or my physical intuition was wrong. I was assuming my math was wrong, but if my math is right, I'm seeking a physical explanation.

Based on my physical intuition of a doublet, this clearly can't be a valid solution, since that involves a discontinuous spike in position (jumps from 0 to 1). Sorry if that was unclear.